# how can I consume a dll that is referenced by another dll?

Tags: c#, .net

I have three separate projects in my solution. Original and Secondary and Console-app. Secondary assembly references to the Original one and Console-app references to the Secondary. How can I use enumerations (types) in Original assembly from console-app without referencing to it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to provide a [example].

Answer (score 0):

Check the [shared projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) for visual studio.

It allows to have code for multiple projects, each projects compile the shared project as his own code, so you don't need to reference the common code.